# Difference between the numbers in cells for a $n \times n$ grid.

Tags: combinatorics

Each cell in an $n \times n$ table is filled with an integer from 1 to $n^2$ without repetition. It is known that the number $1$ does not lie along the border. Prove that there exist two adjacent cells (cells with a common vertex or common side) such that the difference between the two numbers is at least $n+3$.

I was able to prove that the difference would be at least $n+1$, see below:

> We assume that the difference between two adjacent cells is less than $n+1$.
>
> If we place a counter on the cell numbered $1$, the counter will have to move through at most $n-1$ cells to reach the cell numbered $n$.
>
> The difference between the numbers in adjacent squares is less than $n+1$. The counter moves through at most $n-1$ cells, and the difference between adjacent grids is less than $n+1$, therefore the difference between $n^2$ and $1$ would be appear to be less than $(n-1)(n+1) = n^2-1$. This is a contradiction, and therefore the difference between two adjacent cells has to be at least $n+1$

: I've proved that the difference between adjacent cells has to be at least $n+1$ (is the proof foolproof though), however, I need to prove that the there exist two adjacent cells such that the difference between the numbers in those two cells is $n+3$. Did I miss something in my proof? I do not know how to include the requirement that '$1$' does not lie along the border of the cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction is exactly the right idea, but your bounds can be further refined. You know the cell containing $1$ is not on the edge, so only $n-2$ cells will need to be traversed. You can therefore assume the difference between adjacent cells is no more than $n+2$ and arrive at a contradiction.